# Inconsistent line-height being applied to certain tag classes in chatroom and chat transcripts

Tags: bug, design

The [tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) names on beta sites seem to cut into one another due to the nature of `display:inline`:

[image: Exhibit 1]

The class declaration in question are `.ob-post-tag, .ob-user-tag` located in `http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/css/chat.stackexchange.com.css`

However, it does not seem to be an issue with the chat room tags:

[image: Exhibit 2]

There's also no issue with lists items either:

- [some-long-name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/some-long-name)[some-long-name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/some-long-name)[some-long-name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/some-long-name)[some-long-name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/some-long-name)[some-long-name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/some-long-name)[some-long-name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/some-long-name)[some-long-name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/some-long-name)
- [short-name](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-name)

The question tag list on all SE sites do not have this issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to stem from the lack of the following attributes to the above mentioned class definition:

- `line-height` (1.4, to be consistant with other sites)
- `margin` (~2px should be enough)
- `white-space` (set to `nowrap` to keep tags as one block in narrower containers like those in chat)

Adding these missing styles to the `.ob-post-tag, .ob-user-tag` class declaration should resolve this issue.